# Linkedin oauth 1 401

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am currently getting the following error on LinkedIn Oauth 1 (I have to use Oauth 1 unfortunately) when I know my Signature generation etc is fine because I successfully get a token/secret from the provider. The call I'm making is to the profile URL but I get the following response:

```
Response: 

  401
  1425894655948
  63UIYGV64B
  0
  [unauthorized]. OAU:755t1aq1yfza9y|939a9fa9-6b59-4ac6-bd65-bf802e15e9a9|*01|*01:1425894649:1O7tMw+bnVG77ktoGswoyGrM6kg=
```

Any clues as to what that may mean? My server time is < 1 min dif and I know this works on Twitter/Xing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I was going to delete this if I'd done something stupid, but it turns out that when you get your base string for Oauth1 - LinkedIn doesn't like you encoding the ~ sign as %7E. Found the Oauth 1 console at http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/oauth-test/ which helped me solve it.